# Para criar um produto numa loja online, preciso criar uma pagina HTML para cada produto?

Tags: html

a minha questão é: eu estou a criar um site com loja, para um cliente aceder a pagina com os detalhes de um produto, é necessario criar uma pagina para cada produto, ou ha alguma forma de uma pagina ser modificada consoante o produto[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E necessário criar uma pagina como esta para todos os produtos?
se houver alguma outra forma automatizada de faze-lo agradecia que a indicassem ou um video no youtube seria fantástico tambem.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: É apenas um arquivo onde tu vai usar a linguagem de backend que estiveres usando para buscar as informações referentes ao produto em questao e mostrá-las na página.

Comment: mas qual arquivo? eu estou a usar PHP. e as informações do produto estariam numa base de dados em mysql.

Comment: A página que tu for criar pra mostrar essas informações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mais aconselhável é utilizar junto do php, algum Framework para front, como o Angular, ou criar um serviço que retorne o produto e consumir isso com Ajax. 
Um detalhe legal para estudo, se você prestar atenção as grandes lojas de e-commerce simula uma URL para cada produto que o usuário seleciona, porem isso pode ser feito com o ReWrite onde ele gera uma URL diferenciada para seu usuário, sendo que ele esta acessando a mesma pagina de produto, apenas alterando as informações e a URL.